# get form values and store it in sessions using jquery in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, jquery

i am using jquery in the login page , here i need to capture emailid and password and store in the session to use in other pages. how can i store the values entered in session using jquery.

My code

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "home.aspx/ValidateUser",
        data: (JSON.stringify({ emailid: strEmail, password: strPassword })),
        success: function (responseText) {

            var IsUserExists = responseText.d

            switch (IsUserExists) {
                case "0":
                    alert("Your are not registered user. Please register yours before login.");
                    break;
                case "1":
                    LoginToUserProfile(strEmail, strPassword);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    alert("Please activate your account from you registered email and then try to login.");
                    break;
            }
        },
        error: function (responseText) {
            alert("Error in validation --->" + responseText);
        }
    });  
    return false;

}



function LoginToUserProfile(strEmail, strPassword) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "home.aspx/GetUserId",
        data: (JSON.stringify({ emailid: strEmail, password: strPassword })),
        success: function (responseText) {
            var UserId = responseText.d
            window.location = "users/userhomepage.aspx?userid=" + UserId;
        },
        error: function (responseText) {
            alert("Error in LoginToUserProfile --->" + responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

how can i store values of email id and password in session from login.help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to store it within your controller and then to each page that you need to use it (in the UI) create a hidden field filled with the information necessary.

In your url, change the value to `"url: Home/ValidateUser"` and in your Home controller, you should define the ValidateUser action.

```
public ValidateUser(string emailid, string password)
{
  Session["email"] = emailid;
  Session["password"] = password;
}
```

But if you are doing this for authentication, please, reconsider using a more usual solution.

Comment: one more thing i am using in .cs page webmethod.here how can i capture sessions #region ValidateUser

      [WebMethod]
      public static string ValidateUser(string emailid, string  password)
      {
        user objUser = new user();
        string strReturn = string.Empty;
        strReturn = objUser.ValidateUserExists(emailid, password);
        return strReturn;
        }
       #endregion

       #region ValidateUser

Comment: @felipeclopes my code in .cs page  

       [WebMethod]
       public static string ValidateUser(string emailid, string password)
       {
        user objUser = new user();
        string strReturn = string.Empty;
        strReturn = objUser.ValidateUserExists(emailid, password);
        return strReturn;
        }
        #endregion

    #region ValidateUser